# Upload Image in different button and imageView

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-intent, upload

so every time I press the logo button and select camera, the camera appears but cannot embed the preview in the existing imageView. Whereas when selecting gallery, the photo preview will appear but it appears on the imageView ktp preview. Then, when I press the ktp button and select the camera. When I have pressed the portrait button, the camera will be forced close. Meanwhile, selecting an image from the gallery runs well with a preview on the imageView that should be.

why does this happen? what should I fix?

Here's my code:

```
class VerifyFragment : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentVerifyBinding
    private lateinit var selectedImageFileLogo: File
    private lateinit var selectedImageFileKTP: File
    private var selectedImage: Bitmap? = null

    private lateinit var adminViewModel: AdminViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentVerifyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        adminViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactory())[AdminViewModel::class.java]
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Jika izin belum diberikan, minta izin kamera secara dinamis
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                VerifyFragment.CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            // Jika izin sudah diberikan, Anda dapat membuka kamera
        }

        binding.buttonUploadLogo.setOnClickListener {
            showImagePickerDialog("logo")
        }

        binding.buttonUploadKTP.setOnClickListener {
            showImagePickerDialog("ktp")
        }

        binding.buttonVerif.setOnClickListener {
            binding.apply {
                val namaPerusahaan = editTextNamaPerusahaan.text.toString()
                val alamat = editTextAlamat.text.toString()
                val namaDir = editTextNamaDir.text.toString()
                val noTelp = editTextTelp.text.toString()
                val noWA = editTextWA.text.toString()
                val email = editTextEmail.text.toString()
                val npwp = editTextNPWP.text.toString()
                val bidangUsaha = editTextBidangUsaha.text.toString()
                val nib = editTextNIB.text.toString()
                val kbli = editTextKBLI.text.toString()

                val verifSellerData = VerifSellerData(
                    null,
                    namaPerusahaan,
                    alamat,
                    selectedImageFileLogo.name,
                    namaDir,
                    selectedImageFileKTP.name,
                    noTelp,
                    noWA,
                    email,
                    npwp,
                    bidangUsaha,
                    nib,
                    kbli,
                    null,
                )
                adminViewModel.postVerif(verifSellerData,selectedImageFileLogo, selectedImageFileKTP)
                showSuccessDialog()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Jika izin kamera diberikan, buka kamera

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Izin kamera dibutuhkan untuk mengakses kamera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun saveImageToFile(bitmap: Bitmap?): File {
        // Create a file in the cache directory to store the image
        val imgName = "${binding.editTextNamaDir.text.toString()}__${binding.editTextNamaPerusahaan.text.toString()}.jpg"
        val file = File(requireContext().cacheDir, imgName)
        try {
            val stream = FileOutputStream(file)
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream)
            stream.flush()
            stream.close()
            return file
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        throw FileNotFoundException("Failed to save image to file.")
    }


    private fun showImagePickerDialog(imageType: String) {
        val items = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Kamera", "Galeri")
        val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setTitle("Pilih Sumber Foto")
        builder.setItems(items) { _, item ->
            when (item) {
                0 -> takePictureFromCamera(imageType)
                1 -> pickImageFromGallery(imageType)
            }
        }
        builder.show()
    }

    private fun takePictureFromCamera(imageType: String) {
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        takePictureIntent.putExtra("imageType", imageType)
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery(imageType: String) {
        val pickPhotoIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        pickPhotoIntent.putExtra("imageType", imageType)
        startActivityForResult(pickPhotoIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val imageType = data?.getStringExtra("imageType")

            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE -> {
                    val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                    selectedImage = imageBitmap

                    if (imageType.equals("logo", ignoreCase = true)){
                        binding.imageViewLogo.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
                        selectedImageFileLogo = saveImageToFile(selectedImage)
                    } else{
                        binding.imageViewKTP.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
                        selectedImageFileKTP = saveImageToFile(selectedImage)
                    }
                }
                REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK -> {
                    val imageUri: Uri? = data?.data
                    if (imageUri != null) {
                        try {
                            val imageStream: InputStream? = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
                            selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)

                            if (imageType.equals("logo", ignoreCase = true)){
                                binding.imageViewLogo.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
                                selectedImageFileLogo = saveImageToFile(selectedImage)
                            } else{
                                binding.imageViewKTP.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
                                selectedImageFileKTP = saveImageToFile(selectedImage)
                            }
                        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Gambar tidak ditemukan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showSuccessDialog() {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("YEAY")
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Data Verifikasi berhasil diunggah!")
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, _ ->
            // Tindakan setelah tombol OK ditekan, misalnya mengosongkan form atau berpindah halaman
            dialog.dismiss()
            // Selesaikan Activity dan kembali ke halaman sebelumnya
            requireActivity().finish()
        })

        val alertDialog: AlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        alertDialog.show()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
        private const val REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK = 2
        private const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    }
}
```

Here's the visual:
[screenshot of the fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq9z1.png)

I've worked around it by creating two different variables but it's still an error. I want both images that I take from the camera and galleries to be able to display a preview in the Imageview available for further upload to the server with the method of the viewmodel.